# Kademlia Implementation in Java

Tags: java, sockets, dht, kademlia

I want to setup a Kademlia network to connect peers and build a p2p network. I'm going to distribute processing power of nodes within the network. For network I found this Kademlia Java implemented Setup from git.   https://github.com/JoshuaKissoon/Kademlia
 [image]

I want to know how to setup this and use to implement the network. 
I found that

```
JKademliaNode kad1 = new JKademliaNode("Node1", new KademliaId("ASF45678947584567467"), 7574);

JKademliaNode kad2 = new JKademliaNode("Node2", new KademliaId("ASERTKJDHGVHERJHGFLK"), 7572);
```

is used to create 2 instances of the peers and following code to connect them with each other.

```
kad1.bootstrap(kad2.getNode());
```

But that was to connect them in the same program where it's running.

I want to connect them accordingly for different computers. Been stuck here for hours. I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Kademlia protocol you can find in [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45748-8_5), "To join the network,  n node U must have a contact to an already  participating node W. U then performs a node lookup for it's own node ID."

You should have two instance of the nodes.

Instance 1:

```
JKademliaNode kad1 = new JKademliaNode("Node1", new KademliaId("ASF45678947584567467"), 7574);
```

Instance 2:

```
JKademliaNode kad2 = new JKademliaNode("Node2", new KademliaId("ASERTKJDHGVHERJHGFLK"), 7572);
```

You can bootstrap the node2 from node 1.

```
KademliaId id = new KademliaId("ASERTKJDHGVHERJHGFLK"); 
InetAddress ip =InetAddress.getByName("Ip address of the remote node");
Node kad2 = new Node(id,ip,7572);
kad1.bootstrap(kad2);
```